# Fire event if the CSS style is changed by the user?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, dom-events

I'm writing a lightweight htc program for IE 9 (Javascript). CSS3 has a new property called transition, but it doesn't work in IE 9. I'm trying to implement this, but I need to know when a property changes. I'm familiar with `DOMAttrModified` and `onpropertychange`, but they don't trigger if CSS changes the property:

```
a {
color:#FFF;
}

a:hover {
color:#000;
}
```

If you mouseover an anchor, `DOMAttrModified` doesn't do anything. I could use `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `blur`, `focus`, `activate` and `deactivate` and check every time they occur if a property changed, but what if:

```
div:hover a {
color:#FFF;
}
```

The user didn't hover the anchor tag, but CSS changed the color anyway. I think pie.htc has the same problem. I only need a solution compatible with IE 9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an event for "onCSSChange"

How about running a subroutine every 50 ms and checking the current styling.  If the CSS changes, you can fire your own event.

Comment: That's brute, but I think it's the only solution if nobody else answers. I'll wait for a few days...

Answer (score 0):

I think [matrix filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) might help you.

Additionally, I recommend [Cross-Browser Animated CSS Transforms — Even in IE](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/04/05/cross-browser-animated-css-transforms-even-in-ie/)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more cross browser would be to user **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)** or a similar javascript application to test for the browser's ability to preform `transition`, if it cannot, it will add a class name to the root element, which you can target easily with jQuery or a similar framework:

```
$('.notransition div').hover(function() {
    $a = $(this).find('a');
    //Then animate $a.
}, function() { ... });
```

That way you can use the native property if possible, and if not, fallback to jQuery.